# Selenium+Firefox: How can I go with both Firefox binary specification and Firebug extension addition?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firebug

Currently I'm using the following code.

```
var co = require('co');
var WebDriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var SeleniumServer = require('selenium-webdriver/remote').SeleniumServer;

co(function *() { // async
    var server = new SeleniumServer('/path/to/selenium', {
        port: 4444,
        jvmArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.firefox.bin=path/to/firefox'] // Firefox binary specification
    });
    yield server.start(); // await
    var driver = new WebDriver
                 .Builder()
                 .usingServer(server.address())
                 .withCapabilities(WebDriver.Capabilities.firefox())
                 .build();

});
```

Now I need to add Firebug extension to extract Network traffic as `*.har` file. I googled to find [this](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/module_selenium-webdriver_firefox.html):

```
var firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');

var profile = new firefox.Profile();
profile.addExtension('/path/to/firebug.xpi');
profile.setPreference('extensions.firebug.showChromeErrors', true);

var options = new firefox.Options().setProfile(profile);
var driver = new firefox.Driver(options);
```

To see this, the following methods seem to be available:

- `firefox.Options().setProfile()`
- `firefox.Options().setBinary()`

However, `firefox.Options()` always return nothing...

[image]

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/firefox/index.js#L115-L127), the `Options()` function call is supposed to return nothing:

```
var Options = function() {
  /** @private {Profile} */
  this.profile_ = null;

  /** @private {Binary} */
  this.binary_ = null;

  /** @private {webdriver.logging.Preferences} */
  this.logPrefs_ = null;

  /** @private {webdriver.ProxyConfig} */
  this.proxy_ = null;
};
```

You need to use `new` to initialize the `Options` object:

```
var options = new firefox.Options();
console.log(options);
```

which would have a number of methods available, including `setProfile()`, `setBinary()` etc.

Comment: Thanks for rapid answer!